# Problem of return class type with Enums - Swift

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I want to make an enum that returns a class type that conforms to the codable protocol for Networking Layer.

```
enum SearchQueryType : String, CaseIterable{

 case podcast
 case episode

var classType: Any {
    switch self {

    case .podcast:
        return PodcastSearchResponse.self
    case .episode:
        return EpisodeSearchResponse.self
    }
}

static func objectForType <T> (type: String) -> T {
    return self.allCases.first{$0.rawValue == type}!.classType as! T
 }

}
```

the problem is when assigning the generic type from objectForType function I get an error says "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"

```
    func search (for query: String, type: String, sortByDate: Bool) {
    
    let endpoint = SearchResultRequest.searchFor(query: query, type: type, sortByDate: sortByDate)
    
    var objectType = SearchQueryType.ObjectForType(type: type)
  
  
    
    NetworkManger.shared.callRequest(objectType: objectType , endpoint: endpoint) { (result) in

        switch result{

        }
    }
}
```

I tried to return a type that conforms to the codable protocol, but I get an error from the search function that says the expected T.type is not codable.

is there any way to make a function or enum that returns a class type that works with my case?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to make the `search(for:…)` function generic instead?

Comment: the problem is the backend service search only for one type of episode or podcast.so I need to search for the query with each type. I wanted to make an enum that takes a type as a string and returns a class type that conforms codable.

Comment: I still think it would be doable with a generic function, although I admit I don’t completely understand the requirements, and perhaps a protocol that extends Codable and has a property of type SearchQueryType

Comment: I wanted to make it without, if else checking the type.